# Implementing OWIN using existing Database name validation?

Tags: c#, asp.net, owin

I wish to implement OWIN as per the example I could find here:
http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/individual-accounts-in-web-api

However, since this way of working is new to me especially using my self created database I would like some guidance.
I can submit my registration request without a problem.

The post takes me to the AccountController:

```
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [Route("Register")]
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Register(RegisterBindingModel model)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }

        try { 
            var email = model.Email;
            var password = model.Password;

            var user = new users() {
                 Email = email,
                 PasswordHash = password,
                 Password = password
            };

            IdentityResult result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);

            if (!result.Succeeded)
            {
                return GetErrorResult(result);
            }

            return Ok();
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            throw;
        }
    }
```

This triggers the below code:

```
    public ApplicationUserManager UserManager
    {
        get
        {
            return _userManager ?? Request.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>();
        }
        private set
        {
            _userManager = value;
        }
    }
```

ApplicationUserManager:

```
public class ApplicationUserManager : UserManager<users>
{
    public ApplicationUserManager(IUserStore<users> store)
        : base(store)
    {
    }

    public static ApplicationUserManager Create(IdentityFactoryOptions<ApplicationUserManager> options, IOwinContext context)
    {
        var manager = new ApplicationUserManager(new UserStore<users>(context.Get<DaumAuctionEntities>()));
        var dataProtectionProvider = options.DataProtectionProvider;

        // Configure validation logic for passwords
        manager.PasswordValidator = new PasswordValidator
        {
            RequiredLength = 6,
            RequireNonLetterOrDigit = false,
            RequireDigit = false,
            RequireLowercase = true,
            RequireUppercase = true,
        };

        if (dataProtectionProvider != null)
        {
            manager.UserTokenProvider = new DataProtectorTokenProvider<users>(dataProtectionProvider.Create("ASP.NET Identity"));
        }

        return manager;
    }
}
```

But for some weird reason I'm getting

```
 modelState: {undefined: ["Name cannot be null or empty."]}
```

Even though I don't use name anywhere?! Where is this name coming from?

So I presume I'm doing something wrong but it's hard to debug without a clear explanation on how to implement OWIN with an existing DB.

Below my context/entity and users table that I would like to use to store me user data.

context:

```
public partial class DaumAuctionEntities : IdentityDbContext<users>
{
    public DaumAuctionEntities()
        : base("name=DaumAuctionEntities")
    {
    }

    public DbSet<addresses> addresses { get; set; }
    public DbSet<auctions> auctions { get; set; }
    public DbSet<images> images { get; set; }
    public DbSet<users> users { get; set; }
}
```

users : IdentityUser:

```
public partial class users : IdentityUser
{
    public override string UserName
    {
        get
        {
            return Email;
        }
        set
        {
            Email = value;
        }
    }

    override public string PasswordHash
    {
        get
        {
            return Password;
        }

        set
        {
            Password = value;
        }
    }

    public async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager<users> manager, string authenticationType)
    {
        // Note the authenticationType must match the one defined in CookieAuthenticationOptions.AuthenticationType
        var userIdentity = await manager.CreateIdentityAsync(this, authenticationType);
        // Add custom user claims here
        return userIdentity;
    }
}

public partial class users
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> ModifiedDate { get; set; }

}
```

## Edit:

If I add UserName back to my new users object before I try to call CreateAsync, the error is gone but I get another one instead:

```
"The specified type member 'UserName' is not supported in LINQ to Entities. Only initializers, entity members, and entity navigation properties are supported."
```

## Edit II:

I also have this issue in the tutorial code! This is just a freaking bug in .NET?

## Edit III

I tried to do an override as you can see in the partial class Users above. But I still have the same error.

Comment: Could you please submit your `DbContext` and `ApplicationUser` codes?

Comment: Why you added properties like `ID`, `Email`, `Password`, ... ? By inheriting from `IdentityUser` your user object already has. Also when and in which line you get the error?

Comment: The issue is due to the fact that I did not add UserName to my new user before I call UserManager.CreateAsync. If I add the UserName I have the exact same issue as this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28149599/mvc-5-identitydbcontext-and-dbcontext-transactions

Comment: "Name cannot be null or empty." comes from `if (!ModelState.IsValid)`?

Comment: Nope, it actually passes that. It comes from I believe the manager but whenever I try to debug that code the debugger states that it jumped over it (most likely due to the fact that it's an external library from Microsoft).

Comment: Have you a `UserName` column in your database?

Comment: @reaper_unique See my updated answer about "... whenever I try to debug that code the debugger states that it jumped over it "

Comment: @reaper_unique can you share your code on github, so that i can have a look at it?

Comment: As of now i am downloading the project from your referenced link. Let's see if I am able to replicate your error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got it working.

In the end I had to add adjust the partial class Users (which is a table in my SQL database) so that UserName and Password override the fields of IDentityUser (so not like I did in my question):

```
public partial class users
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string UserName {get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }    
    public DateTime? CreatedDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime? ModifiedDate { get; set; }
}
```

I then just had to pass the password and UserName when I created the user:

```
        var user = new users() {
             Email = email,
             UserName = email, 
             PasswordHash = password,
             Password = password
        };
```

Answer (score 0):

> The issue is due to the fact that I did not add UserName to my new user before I call UserManager.CreateAsync. If I add the UserName I have the exact same issue as this: [MVC 5 IdentityDbContext and DbContext transactions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28149599/mvc-5-identitydbcontext-and-dbcontext-transactions)

That issue seems to point to the fact that ASP.NET Identity is using the `UserName` property in a query, but Entity Framework compains that the property is not mapped to  a database column in your Entity model (EDML).

Comment: But UserName and Email are both fields that I'm using from IdentityDbContext which has those two fields so they should be present, no?

Comment: Fields are present in entity types (such as `users`), not context types (such as `IdentityContext`).

Comment: Yeah sorry that should be 'IdentityUser'. I'm using Email and UserName from IdentityUser.

Comment: You need to explicitly map them; mapping inherited from a base class are ignored by Entity Framework.

Comment: How would I go about mapping IdentityUser fields to my own entities? Taking public partial class users as the base.

Comment: It's no different from mapping any other column; SO and the rest of the internet should be able to answer that question.

Comment: I guess I'm not looking good enough because I really can't find what you are implying. Could you please give an example of an SO question that tackles this?

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19940014/asp-net-identity-with-ef-database-first-mvc5

Comment: That doesn't work either. Still get the same error:The specified type member 'UserName' is not supported in LINQ to Entities. Only initializers, entity members, and entity navigation properties are supported.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see many problems with your code

1. Remove the users DbSet from your DaumAuctionEntities class (See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24343246/asp-net-identity-multiple-object-sets-per-type-are-not-supported))
2. Remove the Id property from your users class
3. Set the CreatedDate property when you create a new users inside the Register
   method

Then you should be OK

Also,about:

> Nope, it actually passes that. It comes from I believe the manager but
>   whenever I try to debug that code the debugger states that it jumped
>   over it (most likely due to the fact that it's an external library
>   from Microsoft).

If you wrap the call with a try/catch you'll be able to see the error message

Answer (score 0):

I got few issues with the code you have shared here but not exactly the same as you mentioned. I have shared the example on git for your reference. Try it by your self and let me know if you see any issues.

Git URL - https://github.com/JitJDN/OWINStack

See, code is still the same as yours:

var email = model.Email;
                var password = model.Password;

```
        var user = new users()
        {
            Email = email,
            PasswordHash = password,
            Password = password
        };

        IdentityResult result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);

        if (!result.Succeeded)
        {
            return GetErrorResult(result);
        }

        return Ok();
```

Comment: Thanks, the moment I have the time I'll have a look!